# What weapon/boost combo allows for fastest cash generation?

Tags: angry-gran

There are several boosts and weapons that confer different benefits which can directly or indirectly net you more cash.  It is hard for me to determine the best load out for maximizing cash.

Comment: Getting this game right now; will post when I have the answer.

Comment: @JamesWebster - you're right, the tag was removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the light sabre for its 100% cash bonus, the horseshoe for its cash bonus and then a few headache tablets for the times you miss since the light sabre carries a recovery penalty.

Source: I made this game! =D